# set blur effect full screen in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiblureffect

I want to set blur effect in full screen like gonna app

here is my code i want to set blur effect

```
 let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
 filePathToWrite1 = "\(paths)/\(videoTitle[a]).jpg"
 let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePathToWrite1)
 viewImg.image = img

 let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = viewImg.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

         viewImg.addSubview(blurEffectView)
         view.addSubview(viewImg)
```

Here is img for my Original img

[image]

After blur effect

[image]

And  i want to like below
[image]

Comment: you can use view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.3]

Comment: blur and transparent are fully different thing use [UivisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/) for blurry ness

Answer (score 0):

put this code under `viewImg.image = img` :

```
viewImg.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```